# Passing php objects to $.post()

Tags: php, ajax, object

I would like to pass 2 php objects as data, as they are, to $.post.

```
        $(function() {
            $("button").click(function() {  
                $.post("fight.php",{player: "<?php $player;?>", enemy: "<?php $enemy; ?>"},function(result) {
                    $("#displayFight").html(result);
                });
            });
        });
```

`$player`, `$enemy` are 2 different objects with a few properties each. I would like to pass them as the whole objects they are, so that `fight.php` can deal with them.

I've also tried `serialize`, but to no avail:

```
{player: $("<?php $player ?>").serialize()}
```

How can I do this?

Note: With all the methods I've tried, I either get some 'unknown identifier' or $_POST comes out empty on the receiving page.

EDIT: the json_encode part works, but the decoding fails. On the receiving page:

```
$player = json_decode($_POST["player"])
```

fails and returns an error: `json_decode() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given`

Comment: You could use `json_encode` on them.

Comment: you can only send text over the internet. Your objects need to be able to convert to/from text

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use [`json_encode`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php), like this:

```
$.post("fight.php",{
    player: <?php echo json_encode($player);?>, 
    enemy: <?php echo json_encode($enemy);?>
}, ... );
```

Note that there are no quotes around the `<?php ?>` tags; `json_encode` will add them automatically if required.

Apart from that, you need to be aware of the requirements that `json_encode` imposes: most importantly, if your objects contain string content (either as a property or as a property of any sub-objects) then these strings must be encoded in UTF-8.

Comment: It seems to work at first, but when taking the data out of $_POST, each object comes out as an array. If I try to json_decode() them, I get an error message:  "son_decode() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given". Any idea why?

Comment: @frrlod: jQuery ensures that the serialized form will translate into an array when read from PHP; it is PHP that actually creates the array from the POST data. There is no way to make PHP give you an object out of that data, so from that point on you are on your own. The proper solution depends on what kind of object exactly you intend to get out of the request.

Comment: @frrlod: For the easiest case (a plain `stdClass` object without sub-objects), simply `$player = (object)$_POST['player']` will be enough.

Comment: @frrlod: For the most difficult cases (e.g. complex object with state kept in non-public variables) you will need to write code that deserializes the array form into what you want (this is what I do). If it comes to this you could also use `serialize`/`deserialize` and pass a string instead of using `json_encode`, but this approach still requires custom code from you and has some drawbacks that I don't care for (mainly: you cannot pass the object data "in pieces" from JS and/or HTML, you need to do it all at once from one place).

Comment: Thank you for the time and effort. I believe a simple stdClass will suffice in this case.

Answer (score 1):

To easily communicate between PHP and Javascript you should properly serialize your objects. The easiest way is to call json_encode($player) in your PHP code. Then when you are fetching it again with PHP you need to call json_decode() on it and properly initialize the object. There's no way for PHP and Javascript to share an instance of the object. Only the serialized data.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `json_encode` http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php

```
{player: <?php json_encode($player); ?>}
```

Answer (score 1):

One suggestion could be to JSON encode the PHP object using [`json_encode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php).

However, let's think about this: you have a PHP script generating output. That output - which contains this Javascript snippet and the 2 objects - is sent to the client-side (the browser) where it is executed, and it re-sends those two objects back to the server with an AJAX call.

So an alternative idea might be to simply store the objects server-side the whole time in the session and only send an identifier instead of the entire object:

```
<?php
    // apologies for errors - my PHP's rusty
    $_SESSION[$player->uuid()] = $player;
    $_SESSION[$enemy->uuid()] = $enemy;
?>
$.post("fight.php",{player: "<?php $player->uuid();?>", enemy: "<?php $enemy->uuid(); ?>"},function(result) {
    // ...
});
```

Then the `fight.php` script would restore then:

```
// is this still how PHP handles sessions?
$player = $_SESSION[$_POST['player']];
$enemy  = $_SESSION[$_POST['enemy']];
```

If you're using a conventional framework to build a database driven application, this works particularly well because chances are your objects are stored in a database and can be read out of the database easily - which may be a better solution than using the `$_SESSION` array:

```
// if recollection serves this is CakePHP-ish
$player = $this->Player->find($_POST['player']);
$enemy  = $this->Enemy->find($_POST['enemy']);
```

Comment: Could you explain the first line? Why [json_encode][1], and not json_encode($player)?

Comment: @frrlod - Just a typo. I messed up my Markdown annotation so the hyperlink didn't render properly.

Comment: I like the idea. Wouldn't using a session be problematic due to expiration? I would think using a DB is a better idea, but just for the sake of learning.

Comment: @frrlod : "Wouldn't using a session be problematic due to expiration?" - that depends. How long between the first request and the AJAX call? Do you have any control over your server's configuration(s) so you can change the expiration? Also, what are the lifetime/scope of those objects? These are all questions you should ask while deciding whether session data or a DB are better.